# Getting Android WiFi-only device country when there's no internet connection & no GPS

Tags: android, location, telephonymanager, country

I'm trying to determine the country in which the user/device is located as I need to determine if they are within the EU.

I know I can use this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

And then simply check the countryCode string against the 28 EU Member states.

However, this is only useful on phones (and generally speaking *not* where those phones are [CDMA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso()) (as this is, apparently, unreliable).

I know with a wifi-only device that currently has a live connection, I can fire off a request [here](http://ip-api.com/json), (or other such sites), to get a country code back, however, this isn't an option when a wifi-only device is offline (WiFi switched off).

I **do not** want to add extra permissions to my app, so using GPS is out of the question, are there any other (at least more than slightly reliable) ways I can obtain the country code of a device (using local settings perhaps or something similar).

The reason is that I need to show a dialog **only to EU Users** and if they fire up the app without being online (unlikely, but possible), the app will need to know this info.

I've read many questions on this subject, however, all of those questions are open to suggestions about how to obtain this info *with a live internet connection or telephony device*, they are not specifically regarding off-line devices and it is still unclear to me how I can go about getting this info.

Comment: Location is an external property - without learning about where the device is from the outside either through mobile network, GPS, or Wi-Fi - how do you expect the device to know where it is?

Comment: @MorrisonChang, what you say is clearly true, however I did say '*at least more than slightly reliable*'.  And I was thinking about some way of using local settings, (Language, locale, time-zones etc), however, I have no idea how to correlate this information to at least get a *relatively good* idea of where the user/device may be.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.